# No internet connection on XAMARIN android player

Tags: android-emulator, xamarin.android

i just installed [android emulator by xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/android-player/) and its working fine only one thing that its not connecting to internet i checked the inbuilt wifi setting which is showing as saved in it (dont know why not connected instead )  in xamarin  official website they dont have any documentation related to their emulator.

i just wanna know do this emulator supports network connection or not and if yes then how to enable it ???

Answer (score 1):

Is a weird problem, I can navigate with my Xamarin Android Player without this problem.

Check a few things.

1) Run VS2015 with run as administrator and try again.

2) May be the firewall are blocking the access to internet at the application (Xamarin Android Player). Watch the permissions of your firewall on windows and firewall in the antivirus.

---

Let me know if you can solve the problem

regards.

Comment: thanks for responding man , well i'm on mac not windows. and my android player is receiving connection i checked it

Comment: ok you wanna, internet in the application that your are making?

Comment: hey i just installed another Virtual device in it and its working fine now

Comment: But the xamarin android player work have or not Internet, in your question you say that no have internet

Comment: yes i downloaded another device on my android player and now in this new device my internet is connecting fine

Comment: Interesting try check the SDK and the package installed in that version. In what api of android you need internet. Or you wanna work with the new device that you donwload

Comment: i'm fine with the new one , and thanks a lot for responding man  , i appreciate your effort.